# No programs or applications show up in dash 

Tags: unity, unity-dash, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

There are no programs on the dash list (seacher on appmenu).

Yesterday I logged into my account and I tried to find a particular program, but there weren't any!
Additionally, I tried to view installed programs and manually find programs, but nothing was displayed.

And today, when I wanted to turn on Ubuntu Software Center, it just don't turn on.