# Apps not showing in Unity Dash

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with dash - there are no programs on the list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69456/problem-with-dash-there-are-no-programs-on-the-list)

I have the following problem: apps are not showing in the Unity Dash under Ubuntu 11.10. As far as I remember I did not have that problem under 11.04, but I'm not certain. Most often than not I use apps which are already in the launcher.

I tried using `unity --reset` but that didn't stop the problem from resurfacing.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Did your Applications Lens start yet? If it does not start right away after boot but comes up if you leave it alone for a little while, you may be experiencing [bug 877002](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-applications/+bug/877002).

Comment: I'll check it out in greater detail and get back later. Right now I'm trying out Unity 2D and alternatives such as LXDE.

Comment: I've checked the situation again. The bug seems to merely delay showing the applications in the dash. In my case, in a random manner (at least as far as I can reckon), the applications do not show at all and it is not just a case of a delay of a few seconds. By the way, as in the bug above referred, my system was upgrade from Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: here are rm -R .cache/software-center    .OK now    logout and back in