# Unity dash completely empty all of a sudden. Howto fix?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dash search gives no result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125843/dash-search-gives-no-result)

When I open my dash in unity (Ubuntu 11.10 upgraded from 11.04), it looks completely fine. Once I start typing though, all entries vanish and the dash is completely empty. It worked fine yesterday. Any ideas how to fix that? Can't think of anything, I changed.

Here are some screens:
[image: fine dash until typing]
[image: than broken dash as soon as I start typing]

Edit:
Of course I tried this to no effect:

```
 sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/93893/18612

Comment: Possibly same question asked in http://askubuntu.com/questions/69456/problem-with-dash-there-are-no-programs-on-the-list
check there